# Next.js Images not updating when mapped array changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with next.js  component where when i sort the array like this:

```js
  function sortCheaper() {
    const newProducts = [...products].sort((a, b) => {
      return a.price - b.price;
    });

    setProducts(newProducts);
  }

  function sortExpensive() {
    const newProducts = [...products].sort((a, b) => {
      return b.price - a.price;
    });

    setProducts(newProducts);
  }
```

the other elements of product change on card but not the images; Examples:

elements sorted by cheaper price:
https://imgur.com/a/7ube8ix

elements sorted by expensive price:
https://imgur.com/a/EHpnBoH

as you can see the other parts of the product change meaning that the products array has been sorted successfully (including the images as i see in console.log) but the images themselves do not update their order.

I am mapping over products like this even including the key in the image itself:

```
products.map((product, id) => {
  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <Image
        key={id} // i have tried without this too
        src={product.image}
        alt="alt text"
        width={500}
        height={500}
       />
    </div>
  )
})
```

I have tried the following:

- remove and add key prop to the next Image
- add and remove unoptimized tag to next Image

Comment: With the code you have givne, weirdly I'm not able to reproduce the issue.